# New example environment, with symbol at the end

Tags: formatting, packages, environments

Is there a standard formatted environment specifically used for examples?
I'm writing a document on linear algebra, with the usual definition-theorem-proposition-example structure. Right now when I insert an example, I get something like:[image]

This is a screenshot I took. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
   \hskip -\arraycolsep
   \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
   \array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\let\conjugatet\overline
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{span}
\newcommand\md{\ }
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.0}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.0pt,linecolor=red]{Definition}{Definitie}
\numberwithin{Definition}{section}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.0pt,linecolor=black]{Theorem}{Theorema}
\numberwithin{Theorem}{section}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\numberwithin{lemma}{section}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Propositie}
\numberwithin{proposition}{section}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollarium}
\numberwithin{corollary}{section}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Voorbeeld}[section]
\newcommand{\prooffont}{\scshape}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\tracingpatches
\xpatchcmd{\proof}{\itshape}{\prooffont}{}{}

\usepackage{marvosym}    %Here starts the part you said I should add.
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremseparator{.}
\theoremsymbol{\Large\color{Plum4}\Bat}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Voorbeeld}[section]
\AtBeginEnvironment{exmp}{\AtBeginEnvironment{itemize}{\leavevmode}      \AtBeginEnvironment{enumerate}{\leavevmode}}
```

The 'Voorbeeld' is Dutch for 'example'. The problem I'm having is that I want my text directly aligned underneath the 'example' caption. In this case I used the 'itemize' command, but I want it to apply for all cases. This is what I wish to change:

**Example 4.2.1.** (---text comes here----)

I want the text under the 'example' caption, and also have it closed by some symbol (something other than the tombstone for proofs) at the end so that the reader knows the example ends here. Is there any way I could get this done?

Here another screenshot:[image]

As can be seen, my text immediatly starts after the caption, which is not what I want.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit:** Here is what I mean with a possible reduction of quality-output. I entered as code:

> \begin{equation} \label{2} [v]_{\gamma} = (b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)^T. \end{equation}

But this is what I received:

[image]

Notice the gamma float without being attached to my coordinate vector.

Comment: Please provide an MWE of this screenshot. Delete all packages which are not needed here in order to make it easier for us. Do you want the described behaviour just for enumerations? Your Example 4.2.1. looks like the normal result. Please clarify this a bit!

Comment: I don't want the text right next to the 'example' caption. I want the text to start one line beneath the caption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily with the `ntheorem` package (instead of `amsthm`)  and `etoolbox`. I also loaded the `enumitem` package to improve the layout of itemize environments in such context. Here is a possible code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openany]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathrsfs}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{systeme, mathtools}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{#1}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{relsize}
\let\conjugatet\overline
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ima}{Im}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Span}{span}
\newcommand\md{\ }
%\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}
\pagestyle{plain}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.0}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\abovedisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayshortskip}{0pt}
\usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{blacksquare}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\theoremseparator{.}
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.0pt,linecolor=red]{Definition}{Definitie}[section]
\newmdtheoremenv[linewidth=1.0pt,linecolor=black]{Theorem}{Theorema}[section]
\theoremheaderfont{\bfseries\upshape}
\theorembodyfont{\itshape}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Propositie}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollarium}[section]
\theoremstyle{break}
\theorembodyfont{\upshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\clubsuit}}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Voorbeeld}[section]

\theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
\theoremheaderfont{\scshape}
\theoremsymbol{\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
\newtheorem{proof}{Bewijs}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exmp}{\setlist[itemize, 1]{wide=0em, leftmargin=1.25em, labelwidth=0.7em}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\setcounter{exmp}{1}


\begin{exmp}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item $ (\mathbb R,\mathbb C, + )$ is een reële (en dus geen complexe) vectorruimte. Nemen wij immers een willekeurige scalar $ λ ∈ \mathbb R$ en vermenigvuldigen we een willekeurige vector $ (a + bi) ∈ \mathbb C$ met deze scalar, dan behoort het product $ (λ a + λ bi) $ tot $ \mathbb C$. In dit geval hebben wij dus $ \mathbb R × \mathbb C\to \mathbb C~~\colon (λ,a + bi) ↦ (λ a + λ bi)$.
    \item $ (\mathbb C, \mathbb R, +) $ is geen complexe vectorruimte, $ (\mathbb C, \mathbb C, + ) $ echter wel.
  \begin{equation*} \label{2}{} [v]_{\gamma} =(b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_n)^T.\end{equation*}
  \end{itemize}
\end{exmp}

\begin{Definition}
  A fully understandable definition.
\end{Definition}
\begin{lemma}
  A test lemma.
\end{lemma}

\begin{proof}
  A proof for fun!

  End of proof:
\begin{align*}
    a & =b\\
    a + c & =b + d
\end{align*}
\end{proof}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried adding it to my document, but it then builds forever when I click the 'build' button. I deleted the line \usepackage[amsmath, thref, hyperref, thmmarks]{ntheorem} and then it stopped building and gave me 6 errors. But when I add this line it doesn't work.

Comment: It says: "Package ntheorem error: Theorem style plain already defined."

Comment: Don't load both `amsthm` and `ntheorem`. If you like the amsthm formatting, the `amsthm` option of `ntheorem` provides an emulation.

Comment: Still doesn't work, now it says: \qedsymbol undefined. Maybe I should add a full MWE? I have several other environments and maybe they don't go together.

Comment: Yes, that would make it easier to find what's happening. Can you compile my code?

Comment: Edited it. Also, do you know how I could add some sort of a symbol at the end of an example (as usually done in textbooks), as to indicate to the reader the example ends here?

Comment: That' what I did – although an unusual symbol. Before declaring a new theorem  structure, you have to declare a theorem symbol, which you may choose at will. All declarations are valid for the theorems structures declared afterwards, until some other declaration changes part of the formatting. *Edit* I think I got your problem: I forgot to mention, for the theorem symbol to appear, you have to compile at least twice.

Comment: I couldn't even compile your MWE. I got 56 errors, saying \qedsymbol is undefined. I'm not using the standard QED symbol (white box). I changed it so that it is black. Maybe now somehow this doesn't want to compile with the environment you defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22837/discussion-between-bernard-and-kamil).